# Whats wrong with this url?

Tags: django, django-urls

I am trying to acces the following url  with django.
But i get the following error:

## Result

Using the URLconf defined in WebAPI.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
airports/ ^$ [name='index']
airports/ ^carriers/(?P<code>[A-Z]{3})/$ [name='carriers']
airports/ ^carriers/(?P<a_code>[A-Z]{3})/(?P<c_code>[A-Z]{2})/$ [name='details']
carriers/
```

The current path, airports/carriers/ATL/9E, didn't match any of these.

I can not see what is wrong with  the "airports/ ^carriers/(?P[A-Z]{3})/(?P[A-Z]{2})/$ [name='details']" part.

BTW: all the other urls work.

Comment: Just to clarify the url is: airports/carriers/ATL/9E

Answer (score 2):

I think the regex should be like this:

```
airports/ ^carriers/(?P<a_code>[A-Z]{3})/(?P<c_code>[A-Z0-9]{2})/$ [name='details']
```

Because `airports/carriers/ATL/9E` has a integer in `c_code`:

```
airports/carriers/ATL/9E
                      ^
```